# How to understand Immediately Invoked Class Expression?

Tags: javascript

How can I understand this code and how does it execute? Which one is the parent class and which one is the child class? Why is it written like this? What is its purpose?

```js
new (class C extends class B {
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.foo());
  }
} {
  num = 1;
  foo() {
    return this.num;
  }
})();
```

Comment: Hello.  I have never seen or heard about IICE.  What I see there, **if** it is valid syntax, I would say is the construction of a new object of class C.  That's it.  Only the constructor should run, which is calling `foo()`, but its return value is lost in said constructor, so yes, that's it.  You end up with a new object of class C.  That would be my call.

Comment: class B {
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.foo());
  }
}
class C extends B {
  num = 1;
  foo() {
    return this.num;
  }
}
new C()      
Is it equivalent to this?

Comment: *how does it execute* - because it ends in `()`

Comment: I think your equivalency is correct.  But don't trust me.  Just assign that IICE to a variable, then do `console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(variableHere)?.constructor?.name)`.  See what comes out.

Comment: I tried removing the () and it still runs, it can execute because of new.

Comment: "Why is it written like this? What is its purpose?" There is no purpose. This is toy code to demonstrate a concept.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, class declaration code results in a constructor function, which is named the class name.

So,

```
class B {
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.foo());
  }
}
```

gives a function `B`, which you can use to instantiate class B object like `new B()`.

Now, then, let's replace the part above simply with `B` in your whole code.

```
new (class C extends B {
  num = 1;
  foo() {
    return this.num;
  }
})();
```

You're now seeing another class declaration, which is named `C` this time. The difference from the last class declaration is that this class has an inheritance from class `B`.

Then, the same way, let's replace that part with `C` constructor function.

```
new (C)();
```

Now, the brackets surrounding `C` do nothing effective. So, cleaning up them, it looks a simple object initialization.

```
new C()
```

So, your code does the following:

1. declare class `B`
2. declare class `C` inheriting `B`
3. initialize class `C`

   - class `B` constructor runs

     - call `foo` function of class `C`
   - class `C` constructor runs

However, your code will output `undefined`. It is because `foo()` is called during constructing the new object as class `B`, which is before constructing it as class `C`, where the `num` property of class `C` is initialized.

I don't know the intention of your code, but if you move the property declaration line `num = 1` into class B declaration block, you'll get output `1` from the property.

```
new (class C extends class B {
  num = 1; // <= place it here
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.foo());
  }
} {
  // num = 1; => move it
  foo() {
    return this.num;
  }
})();
```